# Searching through various PDF files

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, pdf

I'm just looking for advice on how I can get my code to operate faster. It's pretty quick right now with searching through 30 3-page PDFs, but I imagine once there gets to be thousands of files to search that it will take longer than I'd like. I can change `SearchOption.AllDirectories` to `TopDirectoryOnly`. I've done some testing though and it seems like what takes the longest is the searching in the files not actually enumerating the directory.

```
 public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searchText)
        {
            List<int> pages = new List<int>();
            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
                for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                {
                    ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                if (currentPageText.Contains(searchText))
                {
                    pages.Add(page);
                }
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        if (pages.Count == 0)
            return null;
        else
            return fileName;
    }      

    protected void txtBoxSearchPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtBoxSearchString.Text == "")
        {
            lblNoSearchString.Visible = true;               
        }
        else
        {
            lblNoSearchString.Visible = false;
       var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"C:\schools\syllabus", "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

                        select new
                        {
                            File = file,
                        };

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                string fileNameOnly = string.Empty;
                string pdfSearchMatch = ReadPdfFile(f.File, txtBoxSearchString.Text);
                if (pdfSearchMatch != null)
                {
                    string domainURL = Regex.Replace(pdfSearchMatch, @"C:\\schools\\syllabus", @"https://mywebsite.com/search/syllabus/");                                
                    string finalSyllabusURL = Regex.Replace(domainURL, " ", "%20");
                    fileNameOnly = Regex.Replace(domainURL, @"https://mywebsite.com/search/syllabus/", "");
                    string pdfHyperlink = @"<a href="+finalSyllabusURL+">"+fileNameOnly+"</a>";                       
                    sb.AppendLine(pdfHyperlink);
                    sb.AppendLine("<br>");                                                          
                }

                Regex regex = new Regex(txtBoxSearchString.Text, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                string domainURLfileName = Regex.Replace(f.File, @"C:\\schools\\syllabus", @"https://mywebsite.com/search/syllabus/");                  
                string finalSyllabusURLfileName = Regex.Replace(domainURLfileName, " ", "%20");
                string fileNameOnly2 = Regex.Replace(domainURLfileName, @"https://mywebsite.com/search/syllabus/", "");
                string pdfHyperlinkMappedDrive = @"<a href=" + finalSyllabusURLfileName + ">" + fileNameOnly2 + "</a>";

                if ((regex.IsMatch(fileNameOnly2)) && (fileNameOnly != fileNameOnly2))
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(pdfHyperlinkMappedDrive);
                    sb.AppendLine("<br>");
                }
                else
                {
                    //moving on
                }                                       
            }

            Panel1.Controls.Clear();
            if (sb.ToString() != "")
            {
                Panel1.Attributes["style"] = "height: 222px;";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(sb.ToString()));
                lblNoSearchString.Visible = false;

            }
            else
            {
                string noResults = "No results matched the specified search string.";
                Panel1.Attributes["style"] = "padding-left: 5px; height: 22px; padding-top: 2px;";
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(noResults));
                lblNoSearchString.Visible = false;
            }           
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also read an interesting c# acrobat remove text from pdf on this page http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-text-edit-delete/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The major bottleneck is most likely in the `ReadPdfFile` method as we are dealing with a `PDF` file.

In your `ReadPdfFile`method, a PdfReader is created to read through **every** page of the document to find the `searchText` and the page numbers on which the `searchText` is found is stored inside a `List<int>` named `pages`.
Once the reader ran through every page, the method returns null or the filename based on whether numbers of `pages` is 0.

What you could do is to return as soon as you have found the text, so that you don't have to look through the entire document for nothing.

---

The method has been renamed to reflect more what it actually performs, and 
the return type has been changed to `bool`, since we only need to know if the file contains the search text.

```
public bool SearchPdfFile(string fileName, String searchText)
{
    /* technically speaking this should not happen, since "you" are calling it
       therefore this should be handled critically
        if (!File.Exists(fileName)) return false; //original workflow
    */
    if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", fileName);

    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fileName))
    {
        var strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            var currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
            if (currentPageText.Contains(searchText))
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are <s>several</s> a lot of hardcoded strings in `txtBoxSearchPDF_Click`. Some of them may be *ok* as they only show up once, but the file paths and URL addresses are repeated several times. Those should definitely be stored in constants. If you ever have a need to update them, it would be far too easy to miss one of them.

I should also point out that this code will only run if *that exact filepath* exists on the target machine. It would be much more portable to pull that file path from a config file.